# Why is the Character output in out parameter getting substringed to some limit in DB2

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, ibm-midrange, cobol

I have created a stored procedure to call with some input parameters and get out related to that. The maximum limit of characters I have given 5000. But on calling the procedure the Output parameter is displaying data of 1KB only out of 4.88KB.The number of characters displayed are 1024 out of 5000. Is there a size limit of showing values?

I am calling the stored procedure in Acess Client Solutions software.

The code is written in COBOL language.
The string variable in code is generating the complete output and is passing it also completely.

Is there any way to like compress data passed from linkage section of cobol code.

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE COMMSQLIB1 / CNNPEDDTL(IN IN_POLNUM CHAR(10) , IN IN_RELATION CHAR(1)
    , OUT OUT_RELATION CHAR(1) , OUT OUT_REL_NAME CHAR(50) , OUT OUT_PED CHAR(5000))
    LANGUAGE COBOL
    SPECIFIC COMMSQLIB1 / CNNPEDDTL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    READS SQL DATA
    CALLED ON NULL INPUT
    EXTERNAL NAME 'OOLSQLLB01/PEDCALL'
    PARAMETER STYLE GENERAL;

CALLING STRING:
CALL CNNPEDDTL('U578810971','I','','','')

OUTPUT:
  Return Code = 0
Output Parameter #3 (OUT_RELATION) = I
Output Parameter #4 (OUT_REL_NAME) = RUCJ CKTU CDEZ                                    
Output Parameter #5 (1 KB / 4.88 KB) (OUT_PED) = Angioplasty & other Invasive Treatments|Bronchiectasis|Chronic Rhinitis|Chronic Tonsillitis|History of Pulmonary TB|Pneumonia|Sinusitis|Abnormal LFTs of unknown cause/Unknown type of Hepatitis|Duodenal Ulcer|Fatty Liver found by Ultrasonogram|Gallstones (Cholelithiasis) or Cholecystitis|Hyperlipidemia (Dyslipidemia)|Gastric Ulcer - medically treated|Gastric Ulcer - surgically treated|Gastroenteritis/Enteritis/Gastroenterocolitis|Hepatitis B|Hepatomegaly of unknown cause|Hernia (all forms)|Irritable Bowel Syndrome/Simple Colitis|Pancreatitis - acute or chronic|Ulcerative Colitis|Endometriosis|Investigation of Chest Pain|Phimosis and Paraphimosis|Renal Calculi/Nephrolithiasis (urinary stone)/Ureteric Col|Diabetes Mellitus|Gout (Hyperuricemia)/Asymptomatic Hyperuricemia|Hyperthyroid|Hypothyroid|Thyroid Gland Disease|Abnormal Spinal Curvature|Cervical Disc Disease|Disease of the Hip Joint|Known history of Hypertension|Disease of the Knee Joint|Gouty Arthritis|Lumbar Sacral Disc Disease|Osteoarthritis|Other Disord...
  Statement ran successfully   (245 ms)
```

Comment: What is the Db2-datatype-and-length of the column(s) in the table(s) that give values to the output parameters in your procedure?  What is the Db2-datatype-and-length of the OUTPUT parameters in your procedure?   What tool are you using to submit the CALL statement?     These facts should be in your question.

Comment: Please don't post images. The SQL client indicates that only the first 
1024 bytes out of 5000 are displayed. This has nothing to do with the procedure itself. Here it shows the first 2.5k, but I can't find any preference in the software, I use last version of IBM ACS (1.1.9.2)